# How to avoid crashing when applying particle system with 10 000 000+ polys?

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I have a pine tree. I made needles with particles. Particle are meshes of small needles, around ~10 polys each.

The number of particles i have is big, needles make around 10kk polys on that tree.

Here is the problem: when i try to apply(convert) particles from modifiers menu, the blender crashes. It just processes task infinitely. I left my PC working for 50+ hours, and it did not worked out.

I think the problem may be this: when applying particles, blender does not kill original particle system, and after applying you end up with applied meshes + particle system itself. So it basically meshes on top of each other. In my case this gives us 20kk + polys, quite big.

Is there a way i can "kill" that particle system while applying particles? Because i think it may be the reason blender is crashing.

Comment: I narrowed down the scope of the problem. It is not polycount that freezes the programm. It is object count. In total i have 900 000 needles on my tree. I was never able to convert those to meshes. I did some tests and i was able to convert 40 000 needles at once. I tryed to convert 50-100k needles, no success. I also did this test: i turned my needle geometry in to 2 edges (yes, only 2 edges, not even faces) and set particle count to 100 000. No success converting this. So when i set my particles to 40 000, blender thinks for about 10 mins, but converts them.

Comment: I gona try converting particle system to meshes 23 times with different seeds to achieve 900 000 + needles i had originally. I'm not sure that i gona get same even distribution of needles in the end, but i see no other choise.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question if you want to add new information to it. The comment section is for comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would think about the necessity of 10 polys per 1 needle. Since 1 would be enough, it would reduce the polycount to a tenth. In case you need a close up, I would suggest setting up another tree with higher density settings. This workflow maybe does not bring you into your " particle kill situation".